# Wrapping Jetpack Compose Row around dynamically-sized content?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to create a row of two buttons in Jetpack Compose, and I want each button to wrap its own content, which is the text "HELLO". I have achieved this by using the .defaultMinSize() modifier on each button. However, I am having trouble getting the row to wrap around its content, which is the two buttons. I have used the .wrapContentSize() modifier on the Row composable, but the height of the row is not adjusting to the height of the buttons as shown in the image.

```
Row(
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly,
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
        modifier = Modifier
            .wrapContentSize()
            .background(LightGrey)
    ) {
        Button(
            modifier = Modifier
                .defaultMinSize(minWidth = 1.dp, minHeight = 1.dp)
            ,
            onClick = { /*TODO*/ },
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(0.dp)
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "HELLO",
            )
        }
        Button(
            modifier = Modifier
                .defaultMinSize(minWidth = 1.dp, minHeight = 1.dp)
            ,
            onClick = { /*TODO*/ },
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(0.dp)
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "HELLO",
            )
        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is due to **accessibility**.
Material components that have a visual size that is lower than the minimum touch target size for accessibility (such as `Button`) will include extra space outside the component to ensure that they are accessible.

If you want to remove it you have to force **`LocalMinimumInteractiveComponentEnforcement`** to `false`

```
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(Gray)
    ) {
        CompositionLocalProvider(LocalMinimumInteractiveComponentEnforcement provides false) {
            Button()
            Button()
        }
    }
```

[image]

**Note:** `LocalMinimumInteractiveComponentEnforcement` requires at least
M2 `1.4.0-alpha04` and M3 `1.1.0-alpha04`. Before you can use **`LocalMinimumTouchTargetEnforcement`** in the same way.